# How to click on a string value which is stored in a variable in selenium?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a code where we have a string stored.

```
getEnvironmentValue = Environment1;
```

I just need to click on the `Environment1` UI element.

I tried with the following piece of code, but it's not working.

```
getEnvironmentValue = Environment1; (the value is dynamic based on the environment)

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name(getEnvironmentValue.toString()));
element.click();
```

Can anyone help me on how to click on a string value which is stored in a variable in selenium?

Comment: print this getEnvironmentValue.toString() and check what it returns...than check that name exists in ur html and also make sure that name is unique.

Comment: I have tried System.out, the Environment1 value is displayed. Also Environment1 is unique in the page (exists only once). Still it does not click on environment1.

Comment: so what error it shows?

Comment: What kind of element is it, and what do you expect to happen when it is clicked?

Comment: @Keith - it's a link, which will in turn take me to another page.

Comment: @Noor - It goes to the exception,

Comment: It prints the below exception - 
 } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("The environment Inventory page is not available"); 
 }

Comment: Hi, It started working when I tried using linkText instead of name. Thanks all!

Comment: @Mathan That's what I was going to ask about next. By.name looks for the attribute "name=" on the element, just like By.id looks for the attribute "id=". You could also do By.xpath("//a[text()='linkString']").